# How to migrate myproject.war file and myproject-ds.xml file to JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, migration, jboss7.x, seam, jboss-4.2.x

Till now i run war file in jboss-4.2.2.GA,windows7 in that i had
 deployed `myproject.war` and `myproject- ds.xml` in server/default/deploye
 then its working fine.

now i want migrate jboss-as-7.1.1.Final,windows7 in that i will
 deployee myproject.war.dodeploye and myproject-ds.xml file in
 standalone/deployments but its shows exception

```
 13:55:29,304 ERROR 

[org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
 (DeploymentScanner-t hreads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation
 failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
 => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jbos s.deployment.unit.\"myproject-ds.xml\".PARSE" =>
 "org.jboss.msc.service.StartEx ception in service
 jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject-ds.xml\".PARSE: Failed to process
 phase PARSE of deployment \"myproject-ds.xml\""}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss AS 7 uses a totally different way for deploying and configuring things. Look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Documentation?_sscc=t) for more info.

Basically, all configuration is now made via one file: **standalone.xml** which is located under /standalone/configuration and you put your war/EAR files under /standalone/deployments.

Also if you have a reference to an external jar, you need to add it as a [module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7).

Comment: There is also a tool to migrate the -ds.xml files:  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-IronJacamarDatasourceandResourceAdapterMigrationTool

Answer (score 2):

you need to create datasource in standalone.xml and create a global module

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/myCRMDatasource" pool-name="myCRMDatasource" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb</connection-url>
                <driver>hsqldb</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>SA</user-name>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <driver name="hsqldb" module="org.hsqldb">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
       </datasources>
  </subsystem>
```

and create in JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/hsqldb/main/module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hsqldb">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="hsqldb.jar"/>
  </resources>

   <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
         <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
     <module name="org.hibernate"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

and put the jar in JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/hsqldb/main/

Comment: thanx for Maddy i have one issue now i am using jboss seam2.1.2 in that we have to declar <jta-data-source>sampleDemoDatasource</jta-data-source>in persistence.xml but when i run this formate in jboss 7 it dnt allow ,when i chaged and run it but its throw exception isService status report
BAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
     service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data
source.java:/sampleDemoDatasource]

Answer (score 0):

Glad it helped.

In order to add Oracle JDBC driver, you need to add Module in the JBoss.

What you need:

1.JBOSS_HOME/modules/oracle/jdbc/main/module.xml, with

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="oracle.jdbc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

2. JBOSS_HOME/modules/oracle/jdbc/main/ojdbc6.jar

Comment: ya i can added both module.xml and standalone.xml same thing as you mensined maddy

Comment: can you please check it this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836688/how-to-deployee-jboss-seam-2-1-2-in-jboss-7

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Maven JBoss AS plugin - [`maven-jboss-as-plugin`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/). You can also use the web console - it's at port 9990. `http://localhost:9990`.

First you need to have a user to access the Management API. That's done using `AS/bin/add-user.sh`

Use [`mvn jboss-as:add-resource`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/add-resource-mojo.html) to add a datasource. See [this example](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/final/examples/add-resource-example.html).

Use [`mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html) to deploy your application.