# How to deployee jboss seam 2.1.2 IN Jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss, seam, jboss7.x, seam2

> Now I am using Jboss-seam 2.1.2 ,jsf 2.0 ,richfaces and jpa till now i
>   am used jboss-as 4.2.2 now I want to migrate  jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.
>
> so now i am make sampleDemo project using seam-gen using jboss- seam
>   2.1.2  and deplyed in jboss 7
>
> finally I got one issue in jboss 7 its not allow
>
> ```
>   <jta-data-source>sampleDemoDatasource</jta-data-source> its not allow in jboss7 changed to
> ```

persistence.xml

```
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence>
              <persistence-unit name="sampleDemo" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <jta-data-source>java:/sampleDemoDatasource</jta-data-source>
   <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="-"/>
      <!-- Only relevant if Seam is loading the persistence unit (Java SE bootstrap) -->
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"     value="@transactionManagerLookupClass@"/>
  </properties>    
  </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

standalone.xml

> ```
>    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
>         <datasources>
>             <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/sampleDemoDatasource"
>                      pool-name="sampleDemoDatasource" enabled="true"
>                 use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
>                 <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mobee</connection-url>
>                 <driver>oracle</driver>
>                 <security>
>                     <user-name>manam</user-name>
>                     <password>manam</password>
>                 </security>
>             </datasource>
>             <drivers>
>                 <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.db">
>                     <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
>                 </driver>
>             </drivers>
>         </datasources>
>     </subsystem>
> ```

gettting ERROR is

> Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999 12:08:10,257 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening
>   on /127.0.0.1:4447 12:08:10,381 INFO 
>   [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread  1-2)
>   Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 12:08:10,690 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774 :
>   Service status report JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied
>   dependencies:
>         service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data
>   -source.java:/sampleDemoDatasource]
>
> 12:08:10,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-4) JBA S015876: Starting deployment of "login.page.xml"
>   12:08:11,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951:
>   Admin con sole listening  12:08:11,080 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015875: JBoss AS
>   7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4401ms - Started 150 of 229 servi ces (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services
>   are passive or on-de mand) 12:08:11,210 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018 559: Deployed "login.page.xml"
>
> IN seam project login.page.xml is located in /view/login.page.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

module="com.oracle.db" looks wrong. This is same path from JBOSS_HOME/modules/ What you might be having there is JBOSS_HOME/modules/oracle/jdbc/main. if this is the case module should be oracle.jdbc.

Comment: ya but i will take like this JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/db/main  so if this is the case module should be com.oracle.db even no pblm i had changed to com.oracle.jdbc still it seems same.

Comment: If you see inside the jar, there is no package com. When Jboss encounters a class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, it checks in modules if there is any oracle/main or oracle/jdbc/main containing module.xml, it will not check for com/oracle.

Comment: thanx for good response ,i chaged to  JBOSS_HOME/modules/oracle/jdbc/main then getting same exception ,i think it seems like JNDI prblm.

Comment: is there any possibility  with out configure datasouce in standalone.xml ?

Comment: directly in the console, but effectively its same as putting datasource in standalone.xml. Look the datasource in console, check if connection is working.